# Resolving FreeBSD pkg conflicts

Tags: package-management, freebsd

I'm having some problems getting my FreeBSD 10.0-RELEASE-p7 system to update via pkg, when I run pkg upgrade, I get a worrying list of conflicts; I usually get scared about how much it's going to remove and simply bail from the process.

I've had this for some time, and I can't seem to find any literature regarding the issue, or how I might go about debugging it. When I asked in #freebsd, I got the response that it'll probably go away in a few days. The issue has now persisted for several weeks.

```
[Tue 14/09/30 09:49 BST][pts/11][amd64/freebsd10.0/10.0-RELEASE-p7][5.0.5]
<dst502@aew6pc07:~>
zsh/3 1001 % sudo pkg update; sudo pkg upgrade;
Password: 
Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
FreeBSD repository is up-to-date.
All repositories are up-to-date.
Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
FreeBSD repository is up-to-date.
All repositories are up-to-date.
Checking for upgrades (595 candidates): 100%
Checking integrity... done (2 conflicting)
pkg: Cannot solve problem using SAT solver:
cannot install package libreoffice~editors/libreoffice, remove it from request? [Y/n]: Y
cannot install package jpeg~graphics/jpeg, remove it from request? [Y/n]: Y
Checking integrity... done (1 conflicting)
pkg: Cannot solve problem using SAT solver:
cannot install package graphviz~graphics/graphviz, remove it from request? [Y/n]: Y
pkg: Cannot solve problem using SAT solver:
cannot install package open-motif~x11-toolkits/open-motif, remove it  request? [Y/n]: Y
pkg: Cannot solve problem using SAT solver:
## Get scared and bail out at this point.
cannot install package gegl~graphics/gegl, remove it from request? [Y/n]: n
pkg: cannot solve job using SAT solver
Checking integrity... done (0 conflicting)
Your packages are up to date.
```

This is a system that I'm using as my desktop, so I've got the LXDE and such installed. This issue is becoming pressing, with ShellShock floating around.

**Edit, /etc/pkg/FreeBSD.conf**, as requested by @uzsolt

```
# $FreeBSD: release/10.0.0/etc/pkg/FreeBSD.conf 258710 2013-11-28 14:24:26Z gjb $
FreeBSD: {
  url: "pkg+http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/${ABI}/latest",
  mirror_type: "srv",
  signature_type: "fingerprints",
  fingerprints: "/usr/share/keys/pkg",
  enabled: yes
}
```

Comment: Please share your repos file!

Comment: @uzsolt: I've had a look in the man pages and can't find any reference to that, where would it be located? I've found a /usr/local/etc/pkg.conf.sample (all commented out) and /etc/pkg/FreeBSD.conf which does have entries.

Comment: pkg.conf.sample is a sample file :) Doesn't FreeBSD.conf contains entries??? Please paste!

Comment: I've edited my question to reflect /etc/pkg/FreeBSD.conf.

Comment: I use ports, not pkg, but I don't see anything being removed and only that your packages are all up-to-date so pkg isn't going to do anything. What the conflicts mean, I don't know, but the ShellShock problem is with bash and not your packages. FreeBSD does not use bash by default.

Comment: I'm aware that shellshock is bash's problem, but I'm on version 4.3.24, and I'd like to upgrade. It seems to me that pkg is failing to run upgrade. The first time it failed like this (several weeks ago now), it did claim it had plenty to do, but then spat out the conflicts you see above. This is what pkg says at the moment, and my system hasn't updated since.

Comment: Did you try and update just one package?

Comment: As it turns out, I can upgrade individual packages, which alleviates the most pressing issue, but the box is still not able to upgrade in general to the latest packages, unless I somehow acquire a list of packages to upgrade manually :-/

Comment: But it says your repo is up-to-date.

Comment: However, it's not as I am manually going through and calling pkg upgrade <pkg_name> on obviously-internet facing and upgrade-requiring bits e.g. firefox, pidgin, bash, etc. and finding almost all of them require updates

Answer (score 3):

After a bit of upgrading individual packages by hand, I stumbled across a conflict with jpeg-8_5, and jpeg-turbo-1.3.0_2, running

```
sudo pkg install -f jpeg-turbo
```

Spat out a load of warnings. I then ran:

```
sudo pkg upgrade
```

And some 2 months worth of upgrades are currently installing "happily".

In summary, manually upgrading individual packages turned up a single conflict which I managed to (for better or worse, your mileage may vary!) force an install to get a fix. I then ran a pkg upgrade.